# npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

Tags: python, node.js, npm

Alright,

After quite some reinstalling, reading I still can't figure what is going on.
I'm trying to run npm install --force on a codecanyon script, reinstalled node to latest version, same as python and build tools, added VCINSTALLDIR to path, restarted windows multiple times and still the same issue.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\denis\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Website\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.2.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python311\python.exe" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Python311\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.11.0"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '19.2.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "19.2.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - will only use this version
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS checking VS2022 (17.4.33122.133) found at:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.4.33122.133) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version does not match this VS Command Prompt or the
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS installation cannot be used.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)  
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\denis\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Website\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\denis\OneDrive\Documents\Website\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

[System Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axKtD.png)

[Build tools 2022 Installed + SDK for windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNC5D.png)

[Env path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIcAN.png)

[Visual Studio Code output of python and msvs_version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZYYn.png)

All mentioned in pictures.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it has something to do with Windows 11, running a VM of Win10 Pro where it executes perfectly with the latest packages.

PS: Windows Build Tools are now embedded in the latest Node, so no need to install them manually. Just Node, Git, Visual Studio Code and restart for PATH to update automatically.